# What if in the architecture, there's 2 different assignments for the same signal, but one of them in a process?

Tags: process, vhdl

I would like to know how should we interpret this vhdl code 
Which hardware is described by the vhdl description?

```
 LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
ENTITY Example IS
PORT ( A,B : IN std_logic,
Y : OUT std_logic); 
END Example;
ARCHITECTURE test OF example IS BEGIN
Y <=A AND B;
proc1 : PROCESS (A,B) IS
BEGIN
IF (A = ’1’) THEN Y <=B;
END IF;
END PROCESS proc1;
END test;
```

Will Y take the values given by the process or will it take A AND B and ignore the process ?

Comment: A concurrent statement is elaborated into an equivalent process. The two drivers are resolved here.

Answer (score 1):

As user1155120 says, you effectively have two concurrent processes, each of which drives `Y`. Think of a process (either implicit and explicit) as a little bit of software that models a little bit of hardware. Two have two processes, so you have two little bits of hardware.

Each little bit of hardware drives the same signal (a little piece of wire, if you like). So, you have a short circuit. So, if both processes drive the same value, `Y` will take that value. If, however, they drive different values, the value of signal `Y` will be *resolved* to `'X'` (unknown) - just like what would happen with real hardware.

---

BTW: your explicit process does not model combinational logic, it models sequential logic. It behaves like a latch. This is because you haven't specified a value for `Y` if `A` is not equal to `'1'`.

Comment: Oh so it's a short circuit ! We just begun studying vdhl so I don't really know how it precisely works, we had this example in our course with no answer. Thank you !